# Web archive link redirects to Stack Overflow host (resulting in error page)

Tags: bug, markdown, error-message, broken-link

**Problem:**
Some links will redirect you to a Stack Overflow error site even though they're correct (as in DOM/HTML representation).

**Test cases which now work:**

- <s>Link in question body here: http://web.archive.org/web/%2A/</s>
- <s>Link in comment: [What was lab.msdn.microsoft.com?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1684224/what-was-lab-msdn-microsoft-com#comment1558717_1684224)</s>

**Test cases which still don't work**

- http://web.archive.org/web//http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Security/AES/AES_v1.html
- http://web.archive.org/web///java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Security/AES/AES_v1.html

Strange enough, I can't reproduce the problem with other links. I hope some SO developer out there can help.

Comment: Very strange indeed!

Comment: Interestingly, *right-click -> Open in new tab* is still b0rked **but** *right-click -> Open in incognito window* works as expected `:S`

Comment: I'd say Archive.org is redirecting back here when it hits a 404, but no `Location` header is sent back, and there is no `<meta http-equiv="refresh">` on the page. Also, it's only SO that's affected: http://jsfiddle.net/rzYxt/show/

Comment: @DannyBeckett It's sending a 302 with a Location header, only sometimes though.